# JavaScript ShellSort something wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```js
var CreateArray = (...lengths) => lengths.map(length => (
 Array.from({ length }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000000))
));
function compareNumeric(a, b) { 
 if (a > b) return 1;
 if (a < b) return -1;
}
var array8 = [];
for (var k= 0, t=100; k<t; k++){
 array8.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 3000000))
};
array8.sort(compareNumeric);

console.time("ShellSort")
function ShellSort(array) {
 var countOuter = 0;
 var countInner = 0;
 var countSwap = 0;
 function createGaps(a) {
  var gapss = [];
  for (var i = 0, j = a.length, t; 1 <= (t = Math.floor(j / Math.pow(2, i + 1))); i += 1) {
   gapss[i] = t;

   if (t === 1) {
    break;
   }
  }

  if (gapss[i] !== 1) {
   gapss.push(1);
  }
  return gapss;
 }
 var gaps = createGaps(array);
 for(var g = 0; g < gaps.length; g++) {
  var gap = gaps[g];
  for(var i = gap; i < array.length; i++) {
   countOuter++;
   var temp = array[i];
   for(var j = i; j >= gap && array[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap) {
    countInner++;
    countSwap++;
    array[j] = array[j - gap];
   }
   array[j] = temp;
  }
 }
 console.log('outer:', countOuter, 'inner:', countInner, 'swap:', countSwap);
}
console.timeEnd("ShellSort")

var ShellSortMultipleArrays = (arrs) => {
 arrs.forEach(arr => {
  console.time("ShellSort");
  ShellSort(arr);
  console.timeEnd("ShellSort");
 });
};


ShellSort(array8.slice())
var arrays = CreateArray(100,500,1000,5000,10000,50000,100000);
ShellSortMultipleArrays(arrays);
```

I want to sort arrays with different lengths(100,500,1000,5000,10000,50000,100000) by shellsort, but i don't understad, why it sort lengths 503,3506,8006,55005,120005,700006,1500006? What's wrong here? And also I don't understand how this "gaps" working here. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Your code could use some comments, the 3-level nested for loop and the createGaps function for loop are doing some pretty funky things which are not so obvious.